# ClassCastException in OpenJDK 10 with Jaxb and SOAP message

Tags: java, gradle, soap, jaxb

I'm getting the following exception which migration Spring Boot microservice that uses SOAP Jaxb using Oracle OpenJDK 10 build using Gradle 5.0. This works find when using Oracle Java 8. The service builds find and runs but gets runtime error when trying to call Backend SOAP service using

```
SOAPMessage response = dispatch.invoke(SOAPMessage message);
```

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.base/java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.base/java.util.List
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:236)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:145)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(DeferredTransportPipe.java:139)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1136)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1050)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1019)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:877)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:463)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.dispatch.DispatchImpl.doInvoke(DispatchImpl.java:265)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.dispatch.DispatchImpl.invoke(DispatchImpl.java:304)
```

Comment: Add the exception stack trace to your question.

Comment: *"I'm getting the following exception"* What exception would that be?? You forgot to actually add it following that statement.

Comment: I added the ClassCastException